# How to open private DNS settings in android programmatically?

Tags: android, settings

Is it possible to open private DNS settings using programmatically in android?

[image: Private DNS page in settings]

Is there any way to set private DNS values programmatically?

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I want to navigate the user to that page in my app.

Comment: I did it using accessibility services, it is not possible to do it directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can only listen, you can't actively switch between the selection and setting of private domain names, and Huawei mobile phones have not been able to dynamically modify the monitoring. The code is as follows:

```
val cMgr: ConnectivityManager = getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    if (cMgr != null) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            cMgr.registerNetworkCallback(NetworkRequest.Builder().build(), object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
                @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
                override fun onLinkPropertiesChanged(network: Network, linkProperties: LinkProperties) {
                    super.onLinkPropertiesChanged(network, linkProperties)
                    println("onLinkPropertiesChanged(Network = $network, LinkProperties = $linkProperties)")
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                        println(
                            "LinkProperties.isPrivateDnsActive = " + linkProperties.isPrivateDnsActive()
                                .toString() + ", server =" + linkProperties.getPrivateDnsServerName()
                        )
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
```